# I need to make a separate buck and boost converter with 200W power rating

Tags: power, pcb, dc, buck, boost

I have to make two converters. One buck going from 240VDC to 12VDC 30 amperes and one boost from 12VDC to 24VDC, possibly with the ability to change from 6 to 30 amperes.

A few more details: The buck will charge a 12 volt 50 Ah Super Bee LiFePO4 Super-B lithium battery. The boost on the other hand will be used from the battery to [power a 24V motor.](https://www.bootman.nl/talamex-tm86)

My main problem is designing the whole thing. I did a PCB but overlooked that I have an enormous power consumption in the final resistor which controls the current.  I have to change to external one that can withstand the current. The only ones that can withstand such power are the aluminum shell wirewound metal resistors.

Second, I need to pick a good gated drive that can withstand the power. Everything that can fit on the PCB will be mounted as a shield to an Arduino UNO for the control of the duty cycle.

This is for a university project.

What do you guys think I should do?

Photo#1 - BUCK
Photo#2 - BOOST

[image: BUCK Schematic:]

[image: BOOST Schematic:]

Comment: Have you considered using a lower value for the current sense resistor?

Comment: Your motor link gives a 404 error. 240 V DC sounds a bit dodgy for a non-isolated step-down converter. Are you sure you're addressing safety properly?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. "[a 24 V motor](https://www.bootman.nl/talamex-tm86)" Apparently it's quite the device. 2.3 pk ([metric horsepower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsepower#Metric_horsepower_(PS,_cv,_hk,_pk,_ks,_ch)), 1,692 W) output for only 864 W input. I'm sure an explanation of how they achieved that scientific breakthrough would make for a much more interesting university thesis than a discussion of boost and buck convertors. Do they have an FTL drive option?

Comment: @GrahamNye curious indeed! Likewise a DIY 240V battery connected to 12V rated wiring on a boat will probably send the user on a one way trip to hyperspace

Comment: Please edit the question to state the source of the 240 Vdc. Is the project being used on a boat small enough to suit the linked outboard motor? The motor is rated for 864 W input so why have you asked about a 200 W converter?

Comment: "the final resistor which controls the current" You can use a low value resistor to sense (i.e. measure) the current. It will need to have a sufficient power rating. (Typically you would want the dissipation (I2R) to be no more than half the rated power of your sense resistor). But I wouldn't expect to use a resistor to control the output current - that's what the converter is for. You can use the current value measured by the sense resistor as an input to the converter control circuit to bring the output current to the desired value. No high power resistor required.

Comment: Please show a circuit of what design you have in mind or a block diagram

Answer (score 4):

Buck will have low efficiency from 240V to 12V, and the lack of isolation is likely to be very dangerous. No-one will expect the 12V side of your installation to carry lethal voltages, so even if it actually uses properly rated wiring it won't be safe because it won't be maintained. And it won't use 240V rated stuff, because the available 12V hardware is not rated for this.

**Especially since it's a boat motor which will involve water.**

It would be much better to use a LLC resonant transformer based converter: efficiency will be higher, and it'll be isolated and safer.

If you want a quick one-off solution, pretty much all mains-powered equipment using a switching power supply begins with a rectifier, which means they will work on high voltage DC unless the PFC chip freaks out when it doesn't see something resembling mains frequency. Some power supplies work "unofficially" and others are specified for DC input use.

So what I'm saying is, you could use a mains powered Lithium battery charger, or you could make one using a constant current output AC-DC converter (otherwise known as "LED driver") and controlled by a simple micro.

Regarding the 12V to 24V converter, the solution is just as simple: if you have a 24V motor, use a 24V battery. This is actually a common question in this forum and the results are never satisfying, because the required boost converter is going to be large, not very efficient, and it will probably cost more than a second 12V battery to wire in series.

If the 240V comes from a battery, then rewiring the battery for 24V will remove the voltage conversion and risk of death.

If the 240V comes from a solar panel and not a high voltage battery, then Victron makes excellent MPPT chargers that will handle everything.